# How to check how many times a user has logged in?

Tags: users

I want to know how many times a user has logged in until a given date in Drupal 7. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think drupal keeps that data as standard. You might want to look at [User Stats Module](http://drupal.org/project/user_stats) which does it for you.

> Provides commonly requested user statistics for themers, IP address tracking and Views integration. Statistics are:
>   1. days registered;
>   2. join date;
>   3. days since last login;
>   4. days since last post;
>   5. post count;
>   6. login count;
>   7. user online/offline;
>   8. IP address;

Comment: one more favour. i can see the count in database. In drupal site where can i find the logged message. i have seen reports but i can't find anywhere

Comment: On *Drupal Answers*, it's best to ask one question per post.  Comments are for clarification to the original question, not for asking new questions.  If you want to ask a new question, just click "Ask question" again and create a new question.  You'll get better answers that way, too.